# Using AddRange without Additional Record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, list

I have a model.

**Stock**

```
public  class Stock
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientAdmin ClientAdmins{get;set;}
}
```

I already fill ProductList and ClientAdminList .ProductList and ClientAdminList Each have 3 records.

```
  var productList = _productService.GetProduct().ToList();

  var ClientadminsList= _productService.GetClientAdmins().ToList();
```

I use AddRange statement for fill stocklist.

```
List<Stock> StockList=new List<Stock>();

stockList.AddRange(productList.Select(x => new Stock { Product = x }));


stockList.AddRange(ClientadminsList.Select(x => new Stock { ClientAdmins= x }));
```

But stockList has 6 records,I want fill stockList by 3 records becuause productlist and ClientadminsList have each 3 records. How can I do it ?

Comment: how do you know that the product list has only 3 records did you checked the database?

Comment: i think @juharr have give you the right answer

Comment: Something is wrong with your model. Both `Product` and `ClientAdmin` classes should have something like `public ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }`, so you should easily fill the list in request from any of those using `SelectMany`.

Comment: @IvanStoev ,If was ICollection how to do it ?

Comment: @IvanStoev But juharr right answered to me .

Comment: I doubt. We'll talk for this another day when you start experiencing problems with incorrect data :)

Comment: just mark the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to zip the two sequences together using [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var StrockList = productList.Zip(
    ClientadminsList, 
    (p,c) => new Stock { Product = p, ClientAdmins = c }).ToList();
```

Note the result will be the smaller of the length of the two sequences.